# How can I load a webpage in a java console application and click a button in that webpage programatically?

Tags: java

I want to load a webpage in a Java console application, fill some text fields, and submit it by clicking a submit button. Is there any Java library available for doing this?

Earlier I tried loading an IE object using powershell from a Java program. It worked well in some cases but I was getting some problems while loading webpages with multiple iframes, so I had to drop that approach and try thinking of a solution fully in Java.

Comment: What's `L`? Is it a typo?

Comment: ah.. i didn't notice that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a testing library like http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/ which can automate clicks etc. on web pages.

Or instead, you can just send the wanted HTTP request (that would have been sent in the browser) directly in Java.

Comment: Thanks .. It looks better than my powershell approach but i am little worried about its dependencies..

Answer (score 1):

Just use [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/), it's the usual way of automating browser interaction.

You simply create a `WebDriver`:

```
WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
```

And navigate to a page:

```
driver.get("http://google.com");
```

You can the select elements by `id`:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("coolestWidgetEvah"));
```

By class:

```
List<WebElement> cheeses = driver.findElements(By.className("cheese"));
```

Or even by XPath if the above two approaches don't suit you:

```
List<WebElement> inputs = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input"));
```

There are many other ways to find elements on the page and to interact with the page.  These examples are all taken from the [Selenium Documentation](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp) which I suggest you read.

Comment: Thanks Boris .. I think this is the kind of solution that I was looking for.